# How to do multiple window transformations in ApcheSparkStructuredStreaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am working on a project on spark structured streaming,in which i need to do aggregations on multiple windows(per min & per hour) on same data.
Facing error: Multiple aggregrations are not supported in streaming Dataframes.

for single window(per min) I am able to do the transformations. But no idea or luck on how to do multiple window tranformations on the same data.

```
df.withWatermark("timestamp", "60 seconds")
  .groupBy(col("assetId"), col("organization"), col("tag"),
   functions.window(col("timestamp"), "60 seconds", "60 seconds"),
   functions.window(col("timestamp"), "3600 seconds", "3600 seconds"))
  .mean("value");
```

Comment: can  you add the code you have tried?

Comment: Thanks for your response, below is the code i tried for multiple transformations                                           df.withWatermark("timestamp", "40 seconds")
 .groupBy(col("assetId"), col("organization"), col("tag"),
 functions.window(col("timestamp"), "20 seconds", "20 seconds"),
 functions.window(col("timestamp"), "60 seconds", "60 seconds"))
        .mean("value");